# Custom list that keeps the padding-left the same as first bullet line

Tags: html, css

I have  a list that needs to look like this

```
aa. Item 1
bb. Item 2
```

I've tried doing this

```
<ol>
    <li style="list-style-type:none;">aa. <span style="padding-left:15px;">Item 1</span></li>
    <li style="list-style-type:none;">bb. <span style="padding-left:15px;">Item 2</span></li>
</ol>
```

This works perfectly, but my problem is when the text expands to line two it looks like this

```
aa. Item 1
Item 1 line continues here
bb. Item 2
```

I need it to look like this

```
aa. Item 1
    Item 1 line continues here
bb. Item 2
```

Is it possible to achieve this? Possible without counters, since it needs to be inline.

Comment: I believe there's a way to customize the list ordering in CSS but I'm looking to find a tutorial.  Otherwise, using your idea, you would just want to mark up the "aa." with a span and make that span inline-block with a fixed width.  That way, regardless of empty or not, you'll have that spacing.  But I don't believe that's a good way about it.  Lots of unnecessary markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link ought to do it for you. I have changed the spans to divs and set them to inline-block.

[link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheWaxMann/KTm9V/)

Comment: Only problem I have now is when the line item is to long, the it pushes the aa. bb. up and then shows underneath it, which is not ideal. Is there a way around this perhaps?

Comment: I have updated my link. By setting a max width on the li and a smaller max width on the div, the div should not overlap the text and should not get pushed down.

Comment: It still gets pushed down with times if the screen display on the browser gets to small, but for my purpose it will work. Thanks again

Comment: Oh yes, so it does. It also seems that it gets pushed down if the text in the li outside of the div is too long :-(

Answer (score -1):

- Add margin-left:20px
- Set list-style-position: outside;
- say 10px padding & line-height: 1.6em

[Result](http://jsfiddle.net/VXQGW/)

Comment: A downvote? hmm with the method above adding<span style="display:inline-block"></span> will work